# PostGIS/QGIS Error geometry has Z dimension when snapping

Tags: qgis, postgis

I am working with QGIS 2.14 and PostGIS 2.3 (for a PostgreSQL 9.5), and I am hitting a strange error.

I have a SHP with some areas, which I would like to include in a PostGIS table (MULTIPOLYGON), manually because I want to add some attribute informations. It works fine when I simply create a polygon, but I want to follow the SHP's polygons, so I activated the snapping option, but when trying to save, I get the error `Geometry has Z dimension but column does not`.

A logical explanation for me would be that the snapping tool create a Z attribute (even if it has a NULL or 0 value), and the error would therefore occur when trying to save this coordinates in a 2D geometry... But that's just a theory.

Does anyone know what is happening when using the snapping ? Is there a consideration of a Z dimension ? And if so, would it be possible to deactivate it ?

Comment: Most likely your source data type has the MULTIPOLYGONZ (3D) dimension, and in the PostGIS table (MULTIPOLYGON), use the ST_Force2D function to do this, just create a copy of the file with the MULTIPOLYGONZ data type first, perhaps it will come in handy in the future ...

Comment: @Cyril Honnestly, this question was almost a year ago, when I was a beginning intern. So I don't even remember having this problem. Thank you for taking the time to answer though :)

Comment: In this case, the moderators need to think over questions and comments that have lost their relevance over time, 1) if the user has figured it out on his own, he must either answer his question or delete it; 2) either leave it as it is, in order for other members of the open community to find a field for answers, somehow so probably ...